# Take a value to a power in InfoPath 2010

Tags: formula, infopath2010

I'm getting a verification error when I try to take the value of a field to a power of another field. Example being:

```
txtfield1^textfield2
```

or even simpler

```
2^2
```

Both fields are formatted as numbers, but InfoPath is telling me that "^" is an unexpected character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfoPath does not have a mathematical operator for the "power to" out of the box. There are 3rd party add-ins that complement InfoPath browser and filler forms (Not SharePoint list forms) with a wealth of functionality, including many maths and financial functions. Have a look at Qdabra's qRules. It is not free, but costs less than a day's developer wages.